# How to convert OpenDocument spreadsheets to a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, libreoffice, dataframe, opendocument

The Python library [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) can read Excel spreadsheets and convert them to a `pandas.DataFrame` with `pandas.read_excel(file)` command. Under the hood, it uses [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) library which [does not support](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/fcfdb721abe650c0b25d8a874dc7314e9eb8dc59/xlrd/__init__.py#L146) ods files.

Is there an equivalent of `pandas.read_excel` for ods files? If not, how can I do the same for an Open Document Formatted spreadsheet (ods file)? ODF is used by LibreOffice and OpenOffice.

Comment: There has been a feature request on pandas github since 2012 [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2311). I don't know why they haven't implemented it yet!

Comment: it is implemented as of August 2019 :)

Comment: The highest voted answer perfectly solves the problem. Perhaps you should accept it?

Answer (score 106):

This is available natively in pandas 0.25. So long as you have **odfpy** installed (**conda install odfpy** OR **pip install odfpy**) you can do

```
pd.read_excel("the_document.ods", engine="odf")
```

Comment: Don't know why this solution does not have an higher number of votes. Before to use pandas you just need to install odfpy with `pip install odfpy`.

Comment: Installed it using `pip install odfpy`
Result is ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'odf'.  Use pip or conda to install odf.

Conda does not have this package.

I believe the problems is that the package is using Python 2.7, which is near it's end of life.

Comment: It can also be installed with `conda install odfpy`

Comment: This works great for me after `pip install odfpy`.  Is there a separate engine needed to write back to that Calc spreadsheet?

Comment: @simchuck the ability to write odf files was added later in pandas 1.1 ; see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/32911

Comment: In more current pandas versions, there is no need to define the `engine`; it is automatically detected. `pd.read_excel("file.ods")` is enough.

Answer (score 19):

You can read ODF (Open Document Format `.ods`) documents in Python using the following modules:

- [odfpy](https://github.com/eea/odfpy) / [read-ods-with-odfpy](https://github.com/marcoconti83/read-ods-with-odfpy)
- [ezodf](https://github.com/T0ha/ezodf)
- [pyexcel](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel) / [pyexcel-ods](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ods)
- [py-odftools](https://code.google.com/archive/p/py-odftools/)
- [simpleodspy](http://simple-odspy.sourceforge.net/)

Using ezodf, a simple ODS-to-DataFrame converter could look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import ezodf

doc = ezodf.opendoc('some_odf_spreadsheet.ods')

print("Spreadsheet contains %d sheet(s)." % len(doc.sheets))
for sheet in doc.sheets:
    print("-"*40)
    print("   Sheet name : '%s'" % sheet.name)
    print("Size of Sheet : (rows=%d, cols=%d)" % (sheet.nrows(), sheet.ncols()) )

# convert the first sheet to a pandas.DataFrame
sheet = doc.sheets[0]
df_dict = {}
for i, row in enumerate(sheet.rows()):
    # row is a list of cells
    # assume the header is on the first row
    if i == 0:
        # columns as lists in a dictionary
        df_dict = {cell.value:[] for cell in row}
        # create index for the column headers
        col_index = {j:cell.value for j, cell in enumerate(row)}
        continue
    for j, cell in enumerate(row):
        # use header instead of column index
        df_dict[col_index[j]].append(cell.value)
# and convert to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

**P.S.**

- ODF spreadsheet (*.ods files) support has been requested on the `pandas` issue tracker: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2311, but it is still not implemented.
- `ezodf` was used in the unfinished [PR9070](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9070) to implement ODF support in pandas. That PR is now closed (read the PR for a technical discussion), but it is still available as an experimental feature in [this](https://github.com/davidovitch/pandas/tree/ezodf_reader) `pandas` fork.
- there are also some brute force methods to read directly from the XML code ([here](http://stefaanlippens.net/opendocumentpython/))

Comment: Works very well. You should provide something like this as an external package (that depends on both `ezodf` and `pandas`) so that users can finally have a read_ods() function !

Comment: with this code python return an error `ValueError: arrays must all be same length` on line 37 `df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)`

Comment: I suppose your spreadsheet has merged cells which causes this error.

Comment: @Ossarotte, I encountered the same error. Turned out it was because two header columns had the same name (so it counted the rows twice). I renamed one of the columns and the error was gone and column-row lenght are all the same.

Comment: @BringBackCommodore64 tanks.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a quick and dirty hack which uses [ezodf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezodf) module:

```
import pandas as pd
import ezodf

def read_ods(filename, sheet_no=0, header=0):
    tab = ezodf.opendoc(filename=filename).sheets[sheet_no]
    return pd.DataFrame({col[header].value:[x.value for x in col[header+1:]]
                         for col in tab.columns()})
```

Test:

```
In [92]: df = read_ods(filename='fn.ods')

In [93]: df
Out[93]:
     a    b    c
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0
2  7.0  8.0  9.0
```

**NOTES:**

- all other useful parameters like `header`, `skiprows`, `index_col`, `parse_cols` are NOT implemented in this function - feel free to update this question if you want to implement them
- `ezodf` depends on `lxml` make sure you have it installed

Comment: I tried your code. It is awesome, except it adds two `NaN` rows at the end of dataframe. have you had similar experience?

Answer (score 6):

pandas now supports .ods files. you must install the odfpy module first. then it will work like a normal .xls file.

```
conda install -c conda-forge odfpy
```

then

```
pd.read_excel('FILE_NAME.ods', engine='odf')
```

Comment: or even just `df = pd.read_excel ('sample.ods')`

Answer (score 5):

### Edit: Happily, this answer below is now out of date, if you can update to a recent Pandas version.
If you'd still like to work from a Pandas version of your data, and update it from ODS only when needed, read on.

---

It seems the answer is No!
And I would characterize the tools to read in ODS still ragged.
If you're on POSIX, maybe the strategy of exporting to xlsx on the fly before using Pandas' very nice importing tools for xlsx is an option:

```
unoconv -f xlsx -o tmp.xlsx myODSfile.ods
```

Altogether, my code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
if fileOlderThan('tmp.xlsx','myODSfile.ods'):
    os.system('unoconv -f xlsx -o tmp.xlsx myODSfile.ods ')
xl_file = pd.ExcelFile('tmp.xlsx')
dfs = {sheet_name: xl_file.parse(sheet_name) 
          for sheet_name in xl_file.sheet_names}
df=dfs['Sheet1']
```

Here fileOlderThan() is a function (see http://github.com/cpbl/cpblUtilities) which returns true if tmp.xlsx does not exist or is older than the .ods file.

Answer (score 3):

Another option: [read-ods-with-odfpy](https://github.com/marcoconti83/read-ods-with-odfpy). This module takes an OpenDocument Spreadsheet as input, and returns a list, out of which a DataFrame can be created.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a few .ods files to read, I would just open it in openoffice and save it as an excel file.  If you have a lot of files, you could use the [`unoconv` command](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-convert-documents-between-libreoffice-and-microsoft-office-file-formats-on-linux) in Linux to convert the .ods files to .xls programmatically ([with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python))

Then it's really easy to read it in with `pd.read_excel('filename.xls')`

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with pandas read_clipboard.
Selecting cells and then copy from excel or opendocument.
In python run the following.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Pandas will do a good job based on the cells copied.

Answer (score 2):

Some responses have pointed out that odfpy or other external packages are needed to get this functionality, but note that in recent versions of Pandas (current is 1.1, August-2020) there is support for ODS format in functions like pd.ExcelWriter() and pd.read_excel(). You only need to specify the propper engine "odf" to be able of working with OpenDocument file formats (.odf, .ods, .odt).

Answer (score 1):

Based heavily on the answer by davidovitch (thank you), I have put together a [package](https://github.com/iuvbio/pandas_ods_reader) that reads in a .ods file and returns a DataFrame. It's not a full implementation in `pandas` itself, such as his PR, but it provides a simple `read_ods` function that does the job.

You can install it with `pip install pandas_ods_reader`. It's also possible to specify whether the file contains a header row or not, and to specify custom column names.

Answer (score 0):

There is support for reading Excel files in Pandas (both xls and xlsx), see the [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-files) command. You can use OpenOffice to save the spreadsheet as xlsx. The conversion can also be done automatically on the command line, apparently, using the [convert-to command line parameter](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/).

Reading the data from xlsx avoids some of the issues (date formats, number formats, unicode) that you may run into when you convert to CSV first.

Answer (score -1):

If possible, save as CSV from the spreadsheet application and then use `pandas.read_csv()`. IIRC, an 'ods' spreadsheet file actually is an XML file which also contains quite some formatting information. So, if it's about tabular data, extract this raw data first to an intermediate file (CSV, in this case), which you can then parse with other programs, such as Python/pandas.

Comment: Thanks. Would be good if there were something more direct, but I guess that's one possibility.

Comment: There is nothing more direct than a file containing the raw data only. Such files must be in a certain file format. There are binary formats for this (such as NetCDF or HDF5), and ascii formats, such as CSV. Unfortunately, CSV is not a real standard. Nevertheless, CSV is pretty straight-forward to deal with in most situations.

Comment: It would be nice to have the .csv get updated if you modify the .ods but that's probably outside of the scope of the answer already...