# Read ods file after uploadind using FileUpload

Tags: python, ipywidgets, ods

I have to make jupyter notebook that can be manualy used to upload .ods files and see it in
I can read xlsx files, but have troubles with ods: i get errors or null df.
How can i read ods file from bytes? Is it possible?

```
uploader = widgets.FileUpload(
    accept='.xlsx, .ods' ,  
    multiple=True  # True to accept multiple files upload else False
)
display(uploader)
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in uploader.value:
    uploaded_file = uploader.value[0]
    bytes_data = uploaded_file['content']
    bytes_data = uploaded_file['content'].tobytes()
    data = BytesIO(bytes_data)
    try:
        df =  pd.read_excel(bytes_data)
    except:
        ##bytes_data = bytes_data.encode('utf-8')
        df =  read_ods(bytes_data)
```

Comment: Based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834995/how-to-convert-opendocument-spreadsheets-to-a-pandas-dataframe#comment116719736_56880160) and deprecation note [here about 'wrap it in a BytesIO object'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) , shouldn't it be `read_excel(data)` for the ods reading step? Also, I'm not following why if you uploaded the file aren't you just using the file object? I have an example of that [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibADJUSTABLE.ipynb). Maybe ...

Comment: <continued> you are using the pyodide kernel in JupyterLite and not specifying that in your post? (I know how you use uploaded files with Pandas in JupyterLite was in flux a bit but I thought it was closer to a typical full Python kernel syntax lately, but maybe not.) Otherwise, I don't see why you'd complicate things by going out if your way not to use the file object?

Comment: @Wayne my mistake. I'm using 'from pandas_ods_reader import read_ods' to read ods.
if i'm using read_excel it also returning empty df. 
I tried BityeIO,  but it didn't work, tobytes() was way to open data from excel.
How can i not to use the file object? FileUpload returning 'content' where is (in content.value) memoryview object layed, so i tried to exctract data from here.
Maybe there is some other ways to do it, but i can't find it. (I have to merge files into 1 sheet, files has to be unploaded manualy).
Thank you

Comment: I'm not following " How can i not to use the file object? "? I referenced an example with all the code [there](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibADJUSTABLE.ipynb). You upload the file and then save the content using Python. Then you would then use the file object. It should read `.ods` because of the extension, based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834995/how-to-convert-opendocument-spreadsheets-to-a-pandas-dataframe#comment116719736_56880160).

Comment: If you want to try the code that includes the upload steps I reference, go to [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#3dscatter_plot-binder) and then click 'launch binder' badge. When the session comes up, choose '3D scatter plot using data in a file and Voila interface' from the list of avalable demonstration notebooks. Run the code as a notebook as it says is an option in the pre-amble; disregard mentions of Voila.